# Discrete mathematics vs. non parametric statistics

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, statistical-inference

Is there any meaningful connection betveen non parametric statistics and discrete mathematics?

I am reading this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Discrete-Mathematics-Technology-Rowan-Garnier/dp/075030135X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/075030135X)

I wonder if it is applyable in some way to chi-square test or kendall tau coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible connections, for sure. The challenge is the fact that discrete mathematics works with discrete objects while the statistics rather prefers to work with continuous quantities.

Let me share one possible idea where discrete mathematics and non-parametric statistics can meet.

One of the most famous fields of non-paramteric statistics is [local regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression). Based on a data set $(x_i,y_i)_{1}^n$ we want to predict the $y$ for given $x\in X$. Typically, a weight $w_i$ is calculated for each record and based on these weights a weighted model is determined to predict $y$ for given $x$. These weights are usually calculated using a [kernel  function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)) that reflects the Euclidean proximity of $x$ and $x_i$. However, it is possible to consider another proximity relation defined on $X$. If $X$ is discrete, it possible to define the [proximity in terms of graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)) that belongs to discrete mathematics.

Comment: Does it relate to level of measurement. Ie. if variable is measured in nominal scale then it is discrete (or no)?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can consider that you have a set of people who may have different level of expertise of a theory. The set is finite and the levels of their expertise can be either finite or continuous scores. Local regression assumes that two persons who are in friendship have similar score. This friendship can be represented as a graph.

Comment: can you name any literature for that what can be understood on entry level? I am wondering if you have group of footbal players which have numbers on their back there is posibility to distinguish which are defenders and which are strikers. It could be done by chi square test and (i think graph analysis)?

Answer (score 1):

They key area of discrete mathematics that is used extensively in nonparametric statistics is combinatorics. Often, you are looking at the number of possible ways to order a set of objects such as ranks subject to constraints. The Mann-Whitney U test, Wilcoxon W, Permutation tests, sign tests...all require essentially combinatorial methods.

**Per OP Comment**

Many non-parametric tests assume exchangeability under the null hypothesis tests. Thus, each set of results has the same probability. As a simple example, permutation tests look at the value of the test statistic under all $n!$ combinations of the samples. A slightly more sophisticated use of combinatorics is for the Wilcoxon Test of a median, where you assume that the sign of a given absolute deviation from the hypothesized mean is equally likely to be positive or negative.

Comment: can you describe in more details combinatorial methods in those tests?

Comment: @user1406647 I added some details. Look up these tests and how the null distribution is developed.